# Text analytics and Insights

Tags: text

I am trying to write an R script for text analytics; trying to analyze  the text for:

- word frequency analysis
- sentiment analysis
- visualize sentiment over time

```
library(tidyverse) # For data manipulation
library(tidyr) # For data tidying
library(dplyr) # For data manipulation
library(ggplot2) # For data visualization
library(tm) # For text mining
library(wordcloud) # For word clouds
library(stringr) # For string manipulation
library(sentimentr) # For sentiment analysis
library(lubridate) # For date manipulation

# Split comments into words
words <- str_split(data$comments, "\\s+")

# Unlist and create a table of word frequencies
word_frequencies <- table(unlist(words))

# Sort and display top 20 words
sorted_word_frequencies <- sort(word_frequencies, decreasing = TRUE)
head(sorted_word_frequencies, 20)

wordcloud(names(sorted_word_frequencies), freq = sorted_word_frequencies, max.words = 100, random.order = FALSE)

sentiments <- sentiment(data$comments)

data$sentiment_score <- sentiments$sentiment

aggregate_sentiment <- data %>%
group_by(market, region, branch) %>%

summarise(avg_sentiment = mean(sentiment_score, na.rm = TRUE)
)

data$date <- as.Date(data$date) # Convert to Date object if necessary

sentiment_over_time <- data %>%
group_by(date) %>%

summarise(avg_sentiment = mean(sentiment_score, na.rm = TRUE))

ggplot(sentiment_over_time, aes(x = date, y = avg_sentiment)) + geom_line()

data$date <- as.Date(data$date) # Convert to Date object if necessary

sentiment_over_time <- data %>%
group_by(date) %>%

summarise(avg_sentiment = mean(sentiment_score, na.rm = TRUE))

ggplot(sentiment_over_time, aes(x = date, y = avg_sentiment)) + geom_line()

top_comments <- data %>%
arrange(desc(sentiment_score)) %>%
select(name, comments, sentiment_score)

top_positive <- head(top_comments, 10)
top_negative <- tail(top_comments, 10)

keywords <- c("service", "quality", "delivery")

data$keyword <- ifelse(str_detect(data$comments, paste(keywords, collapse = "|")), "Yes", "No")

keyword_frequency <- data %>%

filter(keyword == "Yes") %>%

count(market, region, name = "keyword")
```

This is what I was expecting